# Rounded corners changes UIView size

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

In custom tableView cell I would like to create UIView with rounded corners on the top. Here is the part of code where i'm setting the constraints of UIView

```
headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Bellow of this part to set rounded corners of view I have done the following:

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = headerView.layer.frame
rectShape.position = headerView.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: headerView.layer.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [ .topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
headerView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
headerView.layer.mask = rectShape
```

The problem is that when this block of code is used to set rounded corners the size of view is changes. Here is the output

[image]

And the result without this part of code is following:

[image]

My question is why the view size is changing? What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I assume this is probably because you are changing the `layer` of the view, hence affecting auto layout constraints. If all you want to do is round the corners of the view, there's no need to use `CAShapeLayer`

Comment: I would like to have rounded corners only on top, so it is reason why i'm using CAShapeLayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your CAShapeLayer is not automatically resizing once the Header View's constraints are being resized.  You need to update the path whenever the view is resized:

```
  let headerView: UIView!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    headerView = UIView(frame: bounds)
    headerView.frame = bounds

    headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true


    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = headerView.layer.frame
    rectShape.position = headerView.center

    headerView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    headerView.layer.mask = rectShape
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: headerView.layer.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [ .topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
  }
```

I used awakeFromNib just as an example.  Your setup for your view may be different in your custom UITableViewCell class.

Comment: Thanks! This is the right answer. Just i would like to add that the declaration of rectShape must be outside of awakeFromNib, otherwise you will get error in layoutSubviews method

Answer (score 1):

Likely, you are getting the headerView bounds *before* the view is resized to fit the table.

If this in a subclassed UIView, you should probably

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    // update path and mask here
}
```